# Get .length of NEW dynamically added div

Tags: javascript, jquery

6 items are added onload using ajax. Each click, 6 items are being appended.
I want to hide #load-more button if newly added items are less than 6.

How to find the count of newly added items?

I use .length but all items are being counted.
Thanks for your help.

```
var max = 6;
var NewItems = $(".items").length;
if (NewItems > max) {
   $("#load-more").hide();
  } else {
   $("#load-more").show();
}
```

```js
var max = 6;
var start = 1;
var winloc = window.location;
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
if (winloc.hash === "" || winloc.hash === "#home") {
homeurl = `https://mailliw88.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?start-index=${start}&max-results=${max}&alt=json-in-script`;
loadList(homeurl);
}
}).trigger('hashchange')

function more() {
  start += max;
  loadList(`https://mailliw88.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?start-index=${start}&max-results=${max}&alt=json-in-script`);
}

function loadList(url) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.feed.entry) {
        datas = data.feed.entry;
        var entry = data.feed.entry;
        for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
          postTitle = entry[i].title.$t;
          items = '<div class="items"><h2><a href="#">' + postTitle + '</a></h2></div>';
          document.getElementById('showlists').innerHTML += items;
        }
      }
      var newItems = $(".items").length;
      if (newItems > max) {
        $("#load-more").hide();
      } else {
        $("#load-more").show();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='showlists'></div>
<div id='load-more' onclick="more()">
load more
</div>
```

Comment: Consider adding HTML or provide a minimal example please

Comment: just added a reduced version of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
  var newItems = $(".items").length;
  if (newItems > max) {
```

To:

```
  if (data.feed.entry.length < 6)
```

The variable "max" will be out of scope for your "success" method since it's defined outside of it and is an integer type, so you will need to either directly add it, or use an object, like:

```
  var max = {entries: 6};
  ...
  if (data.feed.entry.length < max.entries)
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! the var max still work when I used this on my full code >> if (data.feed.entry.length < max)

Answer (score 0):

You could add data attributes to the new items with an incrementing id so the final html would look like

```html
<div data-load="1"></div>
<div data-load="1"></div>
...
<div data-load="2"></div>
...
```

and then in you're js

```js
$(`div[data-load="${Math.max(...$('div').map(item => parseInt(item.attr("data-load"))))}"`)
```

would get all the latest ajax elements

Comment: thanks for ur answer.  trying to implement this but no success. I just updated my question.